# GORM First Query with Condition

Tags: go, orm, go-gorm

I would like to ask regarding GORM `db.First()` with Condition

Okay, here's an example

```
if err := repository.db.First(&admin, id).Error; err != nil {
    return nil, &response.Error{
        Code: 500,
        Err:  err,
    }
}
```

I know for a fact that this is possible because of GORM documentation stated [here](https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Retrieving-objects-with-primary-key)

But, how about this?

```
if err := repository.db.First(&admin, email).Error; err != nil {
    return nil, &response.Error{
        Code: 500,
        Err:  err,
    }
}
```

Does that the same as this?
`err := repository.db.Where("email = ?", email).First(&admin).Error`

Thanks in advance

I have tried to read the GORM documentation thoroughly, and i can't find any statement that my approach could possibly done. So, i ask here in hope to get some enlightment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`First` method is used to get the first record that matches the condition, and it will check with the primary key field (`id`) by default.

```
repository.db.First(&admin, id)
```

At here, it will generate a query as `SELECT * FROM admin WHERE id = :id`

---

```
repository.db.First(&admin, "an-email@gmail.com")
```

This is not same like `repository.db.Where("email = ?", email).First(&admin)`
here also it will check the condition with `id` field.

`SELECT * FROM admin WHERE id = an-email@gmail.com` - will raise an error

instead, you can try this or the same you have with `where`

```
db.First(&admin, "email = ?", "an-email@gmail.com")
```

As this will check the condition with `email` field.

You can enable the debug mode and it will show you the queries

```
db = db.Debug()
```

See also

- [Retrieving objects with primary key](https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Retrieving-objects-with-primary-key)
- [Logger](https://gorm.io/docs/logger.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: Great! Thanks to laid it out with details. Love your explanation, I've tried it, and it works. Thanks